# How do I run Google Chrome as root?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

I have installed Google Chrome in Ubuntu 10.10. When I try to use in normal user, it is working fine.

Now if I want to use as a root it gives the following error:

> Google Chrome does not run as root

Also when I tried the following command in terminal, it opens Google Chrome:

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir
```

I need a permanent solution for this. Can anybody give me idea about this?

Comment: Just adding my 2 cents here: Overengineered crap. How in the world can it be so difficult to run a program as root?

Answer (score 20):

Run from terminal

```
# google-chrome --no-sandbox --user-data-dir
```

or

Open the file opt/google/chrome/google-chrome and replace

> exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@"

to

> exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@" --user-data-dir --no-sandbox

It's working for chrome version 49 in CentOS 6. Chrome will give warning also.

Answer (score 13):

**First solution:**
1. switch off Xorg access control: `xhost +`
2. Now start google chrome as normal user "anonymous" :
`sudo -i -u anonymous /opt/google/chrome/chrome`
3. When done browsing, re-enable Xorg access control:
 `xhost -`
More info : [Howto run google-chrome as root](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1743565)

**Second solution:**
1. Edit the file `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`
2. find `exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"`
**or** `exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$PROFILE_DIRECTORY_FLAG" \ "$@"`
3. change as
`exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --user-data-dir ”/root/.config/google-chrome”`

**Third solution:**
[Run Google Chrome Browser as Root on Ubuntu Linux systems](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBcZhARzStY)

Comment: this is not a permanent solution

Comment: it doesnot allow me to use /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome when i do this it says google chrome can't run as root

Comment: @Rashmi Sorry,NOT open the file,**EDIT** the file.

Comment: it doesn't make any effect even not able to open or not getting any message.

Comment: @Rashmi Look at (third) video.

Comment: Not working . not able to find under hexaedit

Comment: +1: Second solution works like a charm for me

Comment: Just upgraded from Chrome 21 to 48 on Ubuntu 12.04 (fluxbox). Second solution no longer works — just prints `Aborted`. First solution works. `gksu -wu chrome-user google-chrome` gets it done without disabling X server access control.

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to `/opt/google/chrome`.
2. Open `google-chrome`.
3. Append current home for data directory. Replace this:

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"
```

With this:

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --user-data-dir $HOME
```

For reference visit site this site, “[How to run chrome as root user in Ubuntu](http://computernetworkingnotes.com/ubuntu-12-04-tips-and-tricks/how-to-run-chrome-as-root-user-in-ubuntu.html).”

Comment: mention not. Can you please mark it as a correct answer ?

Comment: It works in Ubuntu 15.04 also.Thanks

Comment: @ashishdhiman2007 Can you please mark it as correct answer ?

Comment: works in ubuntu 16.04 !!!

Comment: @JimitShah Thats great. Can you mark the answer as correct

Comment: @raviranjan : sorry , mark answer as correct is only done by the person who created / asked this question. I can't do it...

Answer (score 5):

i followed these steps

```
Step 1. Open /etc/chromium/default file with editor
Step 2. Replace or add this line 
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--password-store=detect --user-data-dir=/root/chrome-profile/"
Step 3. Save it..
```

Thats it.... Start the browser...

Comment: +1 it's working for chromium. but the question is for google-chrome.

Answer (score 5):

```
I tried this with Kali linux, Debian, CentOs 7,And Ubuntu
```

(Permanent Method)

1. Edit the file with any text editor (I used Leafpad) Run this code your terminal `leafpad/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`
2. (Normally its end line) find `exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"`
   or `exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$PROFILE_DIRECTORY_FLAG" \ "$@"`
3. change as `exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --no-sandbox --user-data-dir`

(Just Simple Method)

Run This command in your terminal

```
$ google-chrome --no-sandbox --user-data-dir
```

Or

```
$ google-chrome-stable --no-sandbox --user-data-dir
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace following line

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"
```

with

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --user-data-dir
```

all things will be right.

Answer (score 2):

It no longer suffices to start Chrome with `--user-data-dir=/root/.config/google-chrome`. It simply prints `Aborted` and ends (Chrome 48 on Ubuntu 12.04).

You need actually to run it as a non-root user. This you can do with

```
gksu -wu chrome-user google-chrome
```

where `chrome-user` is some user you've decided should be the one to run Chrome. Your Chrome user profile will be found at `~chrome-user/.config/google-chrome`.

BTW, the old hack of changing all occurrences of `geteuid` to `getppid` in the `chrome` binary no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

STEP 1： `cd /opt/google/chrome`

STEP 2: edit google-chrome file. `gedit google-chrome`

STEP 3： find this line: `exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"`.

Mostly this line is in the end of google-chrome file.

Comment it out like this : `#exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"`

STEP 4：add a new line at the same place.

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --user-data-dir
```

STEP 5: save google-chrome file and quit. And then you can use chrome as root user. Enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome can run as root (remember to use `gksu` when doing so) so long as you provide it with a profile directory.

Rather than type in the profile directory every time you want to run it, create a new bash file (I'd name it something like `start-chrome.sh`)

```
#/bin/bash
google-chrome --user-data-dir="/root/chrome-profile/"
```

Rember to call that script with root privelages!

```
$ gksu /root/start-chrome.sh
```